# Wrap element with specific code using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to wrap div with specific html code but I'm having problem using jQuery's `.before` and `.after` because jQuery would automatically close div I added into `.before`.

This is my html:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <a>first</a>
    <a>second</a>
    <a>third</a>
</div>
```

When I try using this code:

```
$('.navigation').before('<div class="newNavigation"><a>Prev</a>');
$('.navigation').after('<a>Next</a></div>');
```

He will automatically close .newNavigation div, which is what I don't want to happen because I'm trying to close that div in `.after` code. Generated HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="newNavigation">
    <a>Prev</a>
</div>
<div class="navigation">
    <a>first</a>
    <a>second</a>
    <a>third</a>
</div>
<a>Next</a>
```

And I'm trying to get this:

```
<div class="newNavigation">
    <a>Prev</a>
    <div class="navigation">
        <a>first</a>
        <a>second</a>
        <a>third</a>
    </div>
    <a>Next</a>
</div>
```

To help you little bit with this I created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Klikerko/GXYzV/) where I unsuccessfully tried using `.before` and `.after`.

Thank you in advance!

**Solution:**

Although there was few good solutions I decided to go with @Andy-E suggestion because his code looks cleanest to me.

```
$(".navigation")
    .wrap('<div class="newNavigation">')
    .before("<a>Prev</a>")
    .after("<a>Next</a>");
```

Thank you all for participating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a built-in [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function, use it:

```
$(".navigation")
    .wrap('<div class="newNavigation">')
    .before("<a>Prev</a>")
    .after("<a>Next</a>");
```

> **Demo: [Your fiddle, updated](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/GXYzV/1/).**

This sample highlights how neatly jQuery methods can be chained together.  Here, all three methods return the original `$(".navigation")` jQuery object, so there's no need to use temporary variables or break your code up.

Comment: Thanks Andy, this is very clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) instead.

```
var wrapper = $('<div />').addClass('newNavigation');
$('.navigation').wrap(wrapper);
$('.newNavigation').prepend('<a>Prev</a>').append('<a>Next</a>');
```

Comment: Hi Clive, I'm not sure if you have tested your code but while wrapping works it doesn't prepend and append links.

Comment: Apologies I thought `wrapper` would carry through as a jQuery object...obviously not! I've updated the code and it works on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVz2k/1/)

Comment: Your latest update is much less performant than it could be because it requires invoking the selector engine twice.  This effect is worsened in IE 7 and older, which doesn't support `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @Andy E Agreed, your solution is definitely more efficient

Answer (score 0):

You could try just using .html() like this:

```
// Get the original html from the navigation div:
var navigationHtml = $('.navigation').html();

// Replace the contents of navigation with the original html surrounded by the extra elements
$('.navigation').html('<div class="newNavigation"><a>Prev</a>' + navigationHtml + '<a>Next</a></div>');
```

Comment: Thanks codefrenzy, your solution almost worked. Only problem is that I need "prev" and "next" links to be outside of .navigation div. It's a minor error but thanks for helping anyways!

Comment: Ahh, sorry yes, you're right!  Glad you got a correct answer elsewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".navigatioin").wrap('<div class="newNavigation"></div>');
$(".newNavigation").prepend('<a>Prev</a>').append('<a>Next</a>');
```

should works for you,